# Removing duplicate items from list, ignoring spaces

Tags: c#

I want to remove duplicate items from an array, ignoring spaces, so Distinct.ToArray() won't work.

I copied the array to a list and enumerate backwards through the array with a nested loop. I compare the array item of the inner loop with that of the outer loop. The loop runs without problems, but when I remove an item from the copied list that is indexed to the inner loop, I get an exception.

```
for (int k = aArray.Length - 1; k > 0 ; k--)
            {
                for ( int j = k -1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (Regex.Replace(aArray[k], @"\s", "") == 
Regex.Replace(aArray[j], @"\s", ""))
                    {
                        aList.RemoveAt(j);
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I enumerate through an array and remove items from a copy of that array based on a comparison of items in the array? Thanks.

Edit: Given three strings, one containing NOSPACE, one containing NO SPACE (1 sp), and one containing NO  SPACE (2 sp), but otherwise the same, I want to remove two of those strings. Doesn't matter which two. Distinct won't work because it doesn't ignore spaces, and the suggested answer removes all spaces.

2nd edit: Greg's answer does work, but I can't upvote it (less than 15). I've been struggling with this all day....

3rd edit: Greg's answer works, but removes all spaces in strings. I want to remove items that are identical except for spaces, and leave spaces in items. I still think that enumeration should work, somehow.

Comment: Why doesn't `Distinct()` work? Can you show a sample of your array?

Comment: 2 loops will takes you quadratic time. Could you sort the array? If yes, it's much easier to find duplicated values.

Comment: just friendly advice about *"Greg's answer does work, but I can't upvote it (less than 15)"*: it would be good don't downvote the answer but just add a comment to answer to clarify your requirements or point to some misunderstanding ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = aArray.Select(x => x.Replace(" ", string.Empty)).Distinct();
```

you can use `Regex.Replace(x, @"\s", "")` instead of `x.Replace` if you want to

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = new[] { " 1  2 ", " 12 ", "1  ", "  1", "12", "   1  ", "3 3", " 33" };

var result = array
    .ToLookup(k => k.Replace(" ", string.Empty))
    .Select(v => v.First())
    .ToArray();
```